# Enlarge the output picture and coordinate axis together like Matlab

Tags: plotting, image

Is there anyway to enlarge the output picture and coordinate axis together like Matlab?
Like `MatrixPlot` or other Plot function.

In matlab, there is a zoom button in the picture display window. You can zoom in or out by clicking the Zoom button. The coordinates of the picture will also change accordingly. But I don't know how to do it in mathematica. Or does Mathematica can do this?

like use coordinate matrix `x,y` to plot a image `mesh(x,y,abs(G))`.

The button in matlab:
[image]

---

**Update:**

Matlab can do like this: zoom in/out

[image]

We can see in Matlab, the coordinates correspond to the values of the elements of the matrix when the matrix is drawn. But in Mathematica, it's not so easy to graph matrices in terms of coordinates and zoom in.

Matlab code for A simple example:

```
N=500; 
L=100;
I=zeros(N,N); 
[x,y]=meshgrid(linspace(-200,200,N)); 
[x0,y0]=meshgrid(linspace(-0.5,0.5,N));
lamda_1=632;
lamda=lamda_1/1e6;
k=2*pi/lamda; 
z=1000000;
h=exp(1j*k*z)*exp((1j*k*(x.^2+y.^2))/(2*z))/(1j*lamda*z);
B=fftshift(fft2(I.*exp((1j.*k.*(x0.^2+y0.^2)))));% 
G=h.*B;
figure 
mesh(x,y,abs(G)); 
colorbar
title('Intensity')
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for your reminding, I have updated my question

Comment: Hmm, do you specifically want a GUI button to do this? Or do you simply want to change the plot coordinate ranges (which can be done by modifying the evaluated expression)?

Comment: @thorimur Because sometimes I want to roughly judge the size range of a figure in the picture, it will not be easy to judge if the coordinates can not be enlarged together, So maybe what I want is a GUI button to do the enlarged job with the coordinates together.

Comment: One way to do it might be to enclose everything in a `Manipulate` that lets you adjust the coordinate ranges! (unfortunately I'm not in a position to write it down at the moment, but it should be fairly straightforward)

Comment: @thorimur Thank you for your advice. I will try to think about it.

Comment: Is this drag-select feature only for X-Y view, or it's also defined for the default 3D view?

Comment: @xzczd Both support, it's just that I need more of X-Y view.

Comment: If you only care about X-Y view, then a `Locator` inside `Manipulate` should be good enough. (BTW, I'd argue drag-select in 3D is ambiguous. )

Comment: @xzczd Actually I don't  use 3D view, In Mathematica I usually use ArrayPlot. And because my matrix is so big it takes a lot of memory of my computer to zoom the image. That's where I get confused. When I use Matlab, even though I need a lot of memory to generate pictures, I can zoom in and out smoothly afte the picture is generated. However, when I zoom in Mathematica after the picture is generated, my pictures will take up a lot of memory and my computer will crash. So now I usually figure out the region where I want to see the detail, then I just draw the matrix for that region.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica supports zoom. After you plot, put the mouse on the plot, then click on CTRL and as you slide the mouse up and down, it zooms in and out. Need to hold the CTRL key at same time.

See [RotateZoomAndPanGraphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/RotateZoomAndPanGraphics.html)

[image]

It is also possible to adjust the plot range using Manipulate if you do not want to do the above option.

Using Manipulate, here is a prototype

```
Manipulate[
Plot3D[Sin[x+y^2],{x,-zoom,zoom},{y,-zoom,zoom},
PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-zoom, zoom}},
ImagePadding->30,PerformanceGoal->"Quality"],

{{zoom,1,"zoom"},.1,3,.1,Appearance->"Labeled"},

TrackedSymbols:>{zoom}
]
```

[image]

Adjust as needed. In the above, the zoom slider changes all plot ranges on all the axes by same amount.

**edit**
Reply to comment:

> Well, I really wish Mathematica could add more image viewing
> capabilities

You could use [InteractiveGraphics](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InteractiveGraphics)  for more options.

[image]

But it seems to support 2D graphics only and not 3D. But if what you want is 2D support, the above have many features.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Although it is not the best result I wanted,  it is a way to solve the problem.  By the way the link in the article suggested that the interface I visited did not exist.

Comment: @shrocat corrected the link to Wolfram doc page on zoom. I know it is the exactly the same as Matlab's due to different technologies used by both systems.

Comment: Well, I really wish Mathematica could add more image viewing capabilities.

Comment: `ResourceFunction["ManipulatePlot"]` and `ResourceFunction["DragZoomPlot"]` are also related, but they're only for 2D plots, too.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comment and answer, `Manipulate` is the standard tool for the task in *Mathematica*. If you don't bother to code with `Manipulate` again and again, just define a function:

```
zoom[plot_] := 
 Manipulate[With[{range = PlotRange@Cases[plot, _Graphics | _Graphics3D, {0, ∞}][[1]]}, 
   Show[plot, PlotRange -> scale range]], {{scale, 1}, 0.1, 2}, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

Usuage:

```
zoom@Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
zoom@RevolutionPlot3D[BesselJ[0, r], {r, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

```
zoom@MatrixPlot[
   Re@Fourier[Table[
      UnitStep[i, 4 - i] UnitStep[j, 7 - j], {i, -50, 50}, {j, -50, 
       50}]]] /. (FrameTicks -> _) -> FrameTicks -> Automatic
```

[image]

Comment: In fact, what I want is a magnification of anywhere like matlab, you can click on any location with the mouse to get a zoom within that location range. If I want to zoom a  location range with Manipulate, my idea is to add `a`  and `b` in the variable range : `Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -zoom + a, zoom + a}, {y, -zoom + b, 
  zoom + b}]`, Change `a` and `b` to zoom in on a location range.

Comment: @shrocat I'm sorry but I don't have access to matlab and don't quite understand what functionality you're refering to. Can you elaborate a bit with e.g. a GIF or something? As to GIF creation, you may want to try: https://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. Since I have been very busy recently, I just had time to update my question. I've uploaded a GIF on how Matlab can zoom in on MatricesImage.